# Stopping current operation and proceed to another (new) operation

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function windowResize() {
  someFunction();
  console.log("test3");
}

function someFunction(){
  console.log("test");
  longExecutingFunctionWithAsyncReq();
  console.log("test2");
}

function longExecutingFunctionWithAsyncReq() {
  // some codes here
}
```

whenever the window is resize(zoomed out/in), this function is called.
But if the user spams the zoom, `someFunction()` will not have the time to finish and will then cause the error.

I'm thinking of addressing this issue by stopping the current operation and then process the new operation. Also, I've tried reading about [Deferred and Promise](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/), but I can't grasp the simplicity of the topic and I'm not sure if it really solves my problem. Plus, I've also checked on [callbacks](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp) and was very doubtful that this will not solve my problem either.

If my solution is not possible though, I thought of just queuing the operations, but the downside might be, the queue might overflow if not controlled. As for this solution, I've not looked any farther to this, except reading [about it](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/).

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"! Additionally, your example code only covers vanilla JS - why insist on jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

you could use a `timeout` and clear it before resetting it when the resize function is called:

```
var myTimeout;
function windowResize() {
   clearTimeout(myTimeout);
   myTimeout = setTimeout(someFunction, 500);
}
```

this way the function will be called when the user stops resizing and 500 miliseconds have passed.

Comment: throttling  indeed :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that a function call inside `someFunction` contains some asynchronous requests. I edited my question for farther example.

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to wait for operation to finish you can set up a flag.

```
var working = false;
function windowResize() {
  if (!working){
      working = true;
      someFunction();
      console.log("test3");
  }

}

function someFunction(){
  console.log("test");
  longExecutingFunctionWithAsyncReq();
  console.log("test2");
}

function longExecutingFunctionWithAsyncReq() {
  // some codes here
  // on finish set working to False
}
```

Comment: true/false not True/False

Answer (score 0):

```
var isStillWorking = false;

function windowResize() {
  if(isStillWorking) {
    // Do nothing.
  } else {
    someFunction(function(){
      isStillWorking = false;
    });
    console.log("test3");
  }
}

function someFunction(callback){
  isStillWorking = true;
  console.log("test");
  longExecutingFunctionWithAsyncReq();
  console.log("test2");
}

function longExecutingFunctionWithAsyncReq() {
  // some codes here
}
```

To clarify more of [Anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490486/stopping-current-operation-and-proceed-to-another-new-operation#answer-33491892) I manage to implement the same thing using a flag [global] variable **and a callback**. I use a callback in order to `flag=false` since I also need to wait for the asynchronous requests inside the function to finish before resetting the flag.